# How to Deploy NuxtJS Project on Shared Hosting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, shared-hosting

I developed a NuxtJS project locally and am trying to figure out how to deploy my project to a shared hosting provider list Host Gator.

I want to use the server side rendering functionality of NuxtJS so I will need to run

```
npm run build
```

But once I do that I'm not sure the correct steps to then deploy that built project to shared hosting?

Comment: Nuxt requires NodeJS to run, you would not be able to run it on shared hosting like you would with a PHP CMS. You need to use hosting that can run NodeJS applications. There are plenty out there.

Answer (score 4):

As @AlexanderStaroselsky says, you will not be able to deploy successfully to shared hosting although it isn't because you can't run node, you probably can, it is because you can't run a reverse proxy once you deploy. I once foolishly tried to deploy a nuxt app to Godaddy shared hosting and it was a total nightmare.

I gained shell access and installed node and transferred all the files and ran `npm run build` and then `npm start`. All of this went fine and then was confronted with the issue of how to direct traffic to the nuxt app. On shared hosting you use a .htaccess file to direct to index.php or index.html but you need to make the rewrite rule to direct to http://localhost:3000 which you can put into your rewrite rule but it seems to block the correct functioning of the app. I was able to get the app visible but it didn't have any functionality. The routing didn't work, any images sourced through `require('~/assets/images/...')` didn't display and it was totally unworkable.

What you need is to be able to install nginx to set a reverse proxy and shared hosting never offers root privileges for you to be able to install it. What you need is a cloud hosting provider which gives you a virtual server with full root privileges to install nginx, node, and any other packages you might want. There are plenty of them out there that are affordable (probably more so than shared hosting) and easy to use, such as digitalocean, aws, google cloud, upcloud and so forth.

There can be a bit involved in deploying a nuxt app especially if you are using a rest api and then more so if you wish to add an ssl certificate but there is documentation out there to do it.

All that said, if by some miracle you ever find a way to successfully deploy to shared hosting let me know and I can dust off my godaddy account that I stupidly paid for several years worth of and don't use.

Comment: Is this true even through using statically generated files via `nuxt generate` or `nuxt build && nuxt export` for an SPA?

Comment: @Atenean1, I really don't know if it would work with a static site as I have only tried with a universal site (SSR). Theoretically it may be possible. You would still need node installed I think. If you can, give it a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Atenean1 only nuxt generate can deploy to shared hosting, means those are static website only. But if u running universal I don't know that's why I'm here